# Label are not scrolled and swap with table and their respectieve rows

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll, label, swap

```py
cell_icons = {}
image_references = {}
def on_release(event, label, image_path):
    if label in dragged_icons:
      x, y = event.x_root, event.y_root
      x -= table.winfo_rootx()
      y -= table.winfo_rooty()
        # Identify the row and column under the cursor
        item = table.identify_row(y)
        column_index = table.identify_column(x)
    
        if item and column_index:
            column_name = table['columns'][int(column_index.lstrip('#')) - 1]
            if column_name in ["Trigger Parameter", "Action Target"]:
                current_values = table.item(item, 'values')
    
                # Update the specified column
                img = Image.open(image_path)
                img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    
                cell_identifier = (item, int(column_index.lstrip('#')) - 1)
    
                if cell_identifier in cell_icons:
                    cell_icons[cell_identifier].append(img_tk)
                else:
                    cell_icons[cell_identifier] = [img_tk]
    
                # Keep a reference to the PhotoImage object outside the function
                image_references[(cell_identifier, label)] = img_tk
    
                updated_values = list(current_values[:cell_identifier[1]]) + [cell_icons[cell_identifier]] + list(
                    current_values[cell_identifier[1] + 1:])
                table.item(item, values=updated_values)
    
                initial_x, initial_y, _, _ = table.bbox(item, column=column_name)
                frame_spacing = 5
    
                labels_in_cell = []  # Keep track of labels in the cell
    
                for i, icon in enumerate(cell_icons[cell_identifier]):
                    canvas = tk.Canvas(table, width=25, height=25, highlightthickness=0)
                    canvas.place(x=initial_x + (i * 25 + i * frame_spacing), y=initial_y)
    
                    label_in_cell = tk.Label(table, image=icon, borderwidth=0)
                    label_in_cell.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
                    labels_in_cell.append(label_in_cell)`your text`
```

I included options to swap rows and scroll. When I drop an icon into one of the designated columns' cells, its objects are saved, but the label of the picture is dropped onto the cell. I want the picture labeled to move along with the scrolled and swapped functionality whenever I scroll and swap the table rows, but the labels stay in place and just the stored objects change.

Comment: Widgets added by `.place()`, `.pack()` or `.grid()` into a treeview cannot be scrolled.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example